# Which filesystems support the C attribute?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, btrfs, zfs, xfs

On BTRFS filesystems you can disable CoW for a file using the `C` file attribute, like this:

```
chattr +C filename
```

I expected this to work on ZFS too, since it is also a CoW filesystem, but the attribute cannot be set (maybe ZFS cannot function without CoW).

So what filesystems fully support the `C` file attribute? Do others like XFS or BCacheFS also honor that flag or is BTRFS the only filesystem that does?

---

Context: I created a program that installs a virtual machine, when it detects the host filesystem is BTRFS it disables CoW for the folder with the virtual disk images (because otherwise it introduces performance issues). I applied the same code to ZFS, XFS and BCacheFS but had to remove ZFS because it failed to set the attribute. And now I was in doubt if I need to exclude XFS and BCacheFS too.

Comment: You could test this pretty easily. Create a 1GB file, using `losetup` map it to a device. Create the appropriate filesystem and mount it into your file tree. Test. Unmount. Repeat with a different filesystem. You could then write your own answer and tomorrow accept it too

Comment: You cannot "_disable copy on write"_ on ZFS, it's just built over it. Just for curiosity, what is your context to think about such a thing?

Comment: @ChrisDavies You are absolutely right, but I never worked with any of those filesystems, so it will take some time to figure out how to perform the formatting, etc. I just hoped someone would know the answer so that I didn't have to find out by trial and error.

Comment: `mkfs -t {type}` is the standard user interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chattr`’s `C` attribute [corresponds to the `FS_NOCOW_FL`](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/63f265c857e79bf59982985158154b3edb429e70/misc/chattr.c#L115) flag in the kernel UAPI (defined [in `linux/fs.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.4/source/include/uapi/linux/fs.h#L265)). So the only file systems which support this attribute are those [which handle that flag](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/FS_NOCOW_FL): currently, that’s BTRFS and F2FS.

Note too that file system support can be different for retrieving and setting attributes. There’s no immediate way to check this for BTRFS, you’ll need to read [`fs/btrfs/ioctl.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.4/source/fs/btrfs/ioctl.c) — it supports setting and retrieving the `C` attribute. For F2FS it’s [easier to see](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.4/source/fs/f2fs/file.c#L2001): the `C` attribute can’t be set, it’s only used [to identify pinned files](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.4/source/fs/f2fs/file.c#L3130) (files which can’t be garbage-collected — F2FS is a log-structured file system).